# Using #states in a form with checkboxes

Tags: 8, forms, javascript, ajax

I would like when a client check one of the checkboxes, a text field appeares. Example: if he clicks on 3 checkboxes, all the textfields of the 3 show off. 
My #checkboxes :

```
$form['input']['livraison'] = [
      '#title' => t('Options de livraison (à la charge de l’acheteur)'),
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#description' => t(''),
      '#options' => [
        'home' => $this->t('Retrait chez moi (gratuit)'),
        'hand' => $this->t('Remise en main propre (gratuit)'),
        'myself' => $this->t('Je livre moi-même le produit'),
        'colissimo' => $this->t('Colissimo'),
        'custom' => $this->t('Livraison personnalisée'),
      ],
      '#attributes' => [
        //define static name and id so we can easier select it
        'id' => 'select-shipping',
        'name' => 'field_select_shipping',
      ],
    ];
```

and my textfield :

```
$form['input']['adresse_home'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Adresse',
      '#required' => false,
      '#states' => [
        //show this textfield only if the radio 'other' is selected above
        'visible' => [
          ':input[name^="field_select_shipping"]' => [['checked' => 'false'], ['value' => 'home']],
          ':input[name^="field_select_shipping"]' => [['checked' => 'false'], ['value' => 'hand']],
          ':input[name^="field_select_shipping"]' => [['checked' => 'false'], ['value' => 'myself']],
          ':input[name^="field_select_shipping"]' => [['checked' => 'false'], ['value' => 'colissimo']],
          ':input[name^="field_select_shipping"]' => [['checked' => 'true'], ['value' => 'custom']],
],
      ],
    ];
```

**Solution : **

As berramou sent, this way is the one that works the best with checkboxes. 
 If you have any issues with it look if a plugin couldn't block states, that what happened to me with iCheck. 
If you need to show all the input's checked, just put the TRUE condition in your 'visible', this way you can select 2 options and get both display correctly.

Comment: Reviewing your code comments I dont know french but it seems to me that you will be better using a radios instead of checkboxes, give it a thought

Comment: Unlikely it would have been the best thing to do but ive to give the option to select multiple shipping solutions..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use state for checkboxes element, you should target the specific element by JQuery selector, all elements they have the `name="field_select_shipping"` with `value` attribute different so try to target the input with both attributes try with the following to show adresse_home only if `home` and `colissimo` checkbox checked:

```
$form['input']['adresse_home'] = [
      '#type'     => 'textfield',
      '#title'    => 'Adresse',
      '#required' => FALSE,
      '#states'   => [
        'visible' => [
         ':input[name="field_select_shipping"][value="home"]' => ['checked'   => TRUE],
         // This like AND so the input show if home and colissimo checked 
        ':input[name="field_select_shipping"][value="colissimo"]' => ['checked'   => TRUE],
        ],
      ]
    ];
```

Comment: Thought the same but didnt work https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/290081/2

Comment: @d70rr3s no it's not the same thing,  check jquery selector how to combine two attribute selector, and i test this it works!

Comment: My bad I linked the wrong revision https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/290081/1

Comment: @StefanYYC did you tested this ?

Comment: Yes I did try just now, when I click on it and nothing is showing off

Comment: i tested it it works for me i use Bartik theme, clear cache and test, and also see in the inspect if there is any js errors in the console !

Comment: Check this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BERRAMOU/landing-page/master/assets/images/screencast-drupal-8-7-8.dd_8083-2020.01.gif

Comment: Just a hint OP wants the input tu be displayed only when the option X is selected if any other option is selected he wants to be hidden.

Comment: I just give him the first example, he can do others like this one either in visible state or invisible

Comment: @berramou your solution is working, what was blocking it is a plugin (iCheck) who was overriding the input.

Comment: For example if 'home' and 'colissimo' are checked :  check my update

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is right but you have the wrong syntax.

```
$form['input']['adresse_home'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Adresse',
  '#required' => false,
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name^="field_select_shipping"]' => [['checked' => 'true'], ['value' => 'home']],
     // Omitted the rest.
  ],
];
```

**UPDATE**
As commented [here](https://api.drupal.org/comment/34093#comment-34093) you need to set the name properly which already includes the value. I did not get that to work but using ^= selector and using AND target conditions I got it to work.

An excelent [article](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/form-api-states) about Form States API, thought is Drupal 7 is totally valid.

Comment: I tried to do as you gave me ```'visible' => [
          ':input[name="field_select_shipping"]' => ['value' => 'home'],['checked' => 'false'],
          ':input[name="field_select_shipping"]' => ['value' => 'hand'],['checked' => 'false'] etc...
       ``` Yet nothing is happening just as before

Comment: I did look into the article you linked and I can't figure out where the problem could come from.

Comment: I've upated my answer (my bad I didnt catch that you were using checkboxes element). The issue is the selector, you can also use `':input[name^="field_select_shipping"][value="home"]' => ['checked' => 'true'],` both are valid CSS selectors

Comment: I will try with ```':input[name="field_select_shipping[home]"]'``` and come back to give you a feedback!

Comment: I tried and this time all the textfields are showing as soon as you arrive on the page :/. ```':input[name="field_select_shipping[home]"]' => ['checked' => 'true'],
          ':input[name="field_select_shipping[hand]"]' => ['checked' => 'false']``` Should I try to put only when checked is on true ?

Comment: I've updated the answer I made a test using a site I'm running. Give it a try.

Comment: I just tried but unlikely it doesn't work again, do you think I should only put the checked true ? I edited my question to put the code I'm using rn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103249/discussion-between-stefanyyc-and-d70rr3s).

Answer (score 0):

In a custom form, you need to look at how names are written in the DOM. The name includes the id in brackets, so you need to add that in the state selector. Here's a working example:

```
$form['check'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => $this->t("Title"),
  '#options' => [
    'OPT1' => $this->t("Option 1"),
    'OPT2' => $this->t("Option 2"),
    'OPT3' => $this->t("Option 3"),
  ],
];

$form['example'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => $this->t("Example"),
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="check[OPT3]"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
    ],
  ]
];
```